# App : Application,INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't raise NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, inotifypropertychanged

`class App : Application,INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't raise `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

I want update fill property from other class (path in `App.xaml` in style) .I want to do it from other class.Like this: `App.xaml.cs`

```
public bool isShuffle {
    get {
      return _isShufle;
    }
    set {
        _isShufle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("isShuffle"));
    }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Path Height="59"
      Data="M15.999,4.3080001 C17.228001,4.309 18.402,4.5219998 19.514,4.8779998 L18.6"
      Fill="{Binding isShuffle ,
                     Converter={StaticResource AudioColor}}"
      />
```

But nothing updates.

Comment: Whats your code for OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
      var tempEvent = PropertyChanged;
      if (tempEvent != null) {
        tempEvent(this, e);
      }
    }

Comment: What is the code for your converter? It has to take a boolean value and convert it to a `Brush` (not a `Color`). The converter is the most likely cause of the problem as the binding and property are not perfect but look OK. Please provide Xaml of page & App.xal and Converter code.

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool isShuffle {
      get {
        return _isShufle;
      }
      set {
        if (_isShufle != value){
         _isShufle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("isShuffle");
```

}
          }
        }

```
// Create the RaisePropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Also, you need to make sure you're setting the Context for the binding. For example, you can use `ElementName` if you're not setting the DataContext already.

```
`<Application 
    x:Class="MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/p...
    x:Name="control" ...`
```

And your binding itself

```
<Path Height="59"
                            Data="M15.999,4.3080001 C17.228001,4.309 18.402,4.5219998 19.514,4.8779998 L18.6"
                            Fill="{Binding Path=IsShuffle, ElementName=control, Converter={StaticResource AudioColor}}"
                            />
```

Comment: I do everything that you said, but no success.If I do it on local page, everything works, but when I tried to set Path to global element(in App.xaml) I can't get it works yet.